# SELinux, MySQL, and shared memory

Tags: mysql, selinux

On an SELinux enabled Oracle Linux 6 host, I have a product using MySQL as its underlying database and, through the database, is trying to access `/dev/shm`. `/dev/shm` mounts with context `tmpfs_t`, by default.

Of course, `mysqld_t` doesn't have rights to `tmpfs_t`...

My take is that the best solution is to give the `mysqld_t` context rights to interact with `tmpfs_t`, since `mysqld_tmp_t` and `tmp_t` are already accessible.

Unfortunately, this getting deeper into the weeds of SELinux than most documentation goes into. Most hints, including [Red Hat bug 306351](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=306351), suggest I add a mount option to `/dev/shm` to mount it as `tmp_t`. I'm leaning against that, because I think `tmpfs_t` is appropriate for `/dev/shm`.

So, how do I give the `mysqld_t` type `read()`, `write()`, `getattr()`, `setattr()`, etc., access to `tmpfs_t`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best choice isn't to do it by hand, but through more SELinux automation.

```
grep mysqld /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep shm | audit2allow -M mysql_tmpfs

semodule -i mysql_tmpfs.pp
```

The [audit2allow(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2allow) man page says the `-M` argument uses the next string as the new module name. Between that and the [semodule(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/semodule) man page, I want to use a module name that doesn't already exist. That way, I avoid accidentally replacing a more complete module with my one-off.

Comment: (Incidentally, the lack of hash characters at the front of my commands to represent root user prompts is deliberate. With them, someone needs to put considerable effort into copying and pasting the lines for their own use. Without the hashes, someone can just c/p the entire line.)